# Order by select().distinct()?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I order by `.select().distinct()` ?

Controller method:

```
@line_items_sold = LineItem.where()
@vendor_line_items = @line_items_sold.select(:store_title).distinct
```

View Loop:

```
<% @vendor_line_items.map do |li| %>
    <%= li.store_title %>
    <%= @line_items_sold.where(store_title: li.store_title).count %>
<% end %>
```

I don't even know where to start with this.  I would like to sort the loop by the `count` of the unique/distinct `store_title`.  How can I sort by the instance variables very own variable?

Update: Using PG

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: @SebastianPalma pg

Comment: You can just append `order(:store_title)` to `@vendor_line_items`.

Comment: This is pretty much a textbook N+1 query issue. Every iteration of the loop will cause a SQL query which can be very slow. You could get better answers here if you provide details of your schema and some example data and the expected result instead of overfocusing on what your proposed solution to the problem is.

Comment: @SebastianPalma This sorts by the `:store_title` by abc order, or it's a coincident .  but it's definitely not ordering by the count

Comment: You can order and then count, did you try that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller

```
@vendor_line_items = LineItem.group(:store_title)
                             .select('COUNT(*) as count', 'store_title')
                             .order('count')
```

View

```
<% @vendor_line_items.map do |li| %>
    <%= li.store_title %>
    <%= li.count %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks that is a much simpler approach.   But yeah i now need to sort by the count

Comment: You can append the ordering. I've edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks.  That works!!!  Is there any benefit in either direction from your answer compared to the one I made that gives a hash?

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work this way:

If anyone has any better ways, please let me know

controller

```
@vendor_line_items = LineItem.where().group(:store_title).order(count_all: :desc).count
```

Views:

```
<% @vendor_line_items.map do |li| %>
    <%= li[0] %>
    <%= li[1]%>
<% end %>
```